# Service class and Rxjs subject in Angular for reactivity

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to learn a few things.
I made a system for login/register where a user can login or register. I'm trying now to make a way to  persist the user to be logged in on refresh by checking if he has a token in the localStorage.

I did that, but, my question for you is that:

I have a `authService` that has a property `userFetched: boolean = false`. I inject the authService in the `app.component.ts` and inside the app component I have `ngOnInit` where I send a simple post request to the backend to verify the token (if he has), then if all ok, I set `this.authService.userFetched = true` from within app component.

Then in my `app.component.html` it seems to reflect the changes, also in other components as well. It seems to be reactive when the value changes/update.

Is this a good approach or should I use Subject using Rxjs instead of simple service property?

```js
// app.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthService } from "./services/auth.service";

@Component({
    selector: "app-root",
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(protected authService: AuthService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log("called");
        console.log("called with:", this.authService.userFetched);
        
        if(localStorage.getItem('token') !== null) {
          // bla bla...
          this.authService.userFetched = true;
        }
    }
}

// app.component.html

<div>User fetched: {{ authService.userFetched }}</div>
<app-navigation></app-navigation>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>


// AuthService

import { Injectable, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, of, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";
import { catchError } from "rxjs/operators";

interface User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    email: string;
}

interface UserCredentials {
    name: string;
    password: string;
}

@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root",
})
export class AuthService implements OnInit {
    public userFetched: Boolean = false;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
}

// rest of the code...
```

I've made also a way to change (just for test) the `userFetched` when you click a button, and it also works. But is it a good approach?

Comment: Angular v16 introduced signals, which are a reactive primative. That may be worth checking out for your scenario. Check out this video for more info: https://youtu.be/oqYQG7QMdzw

Comment: This sound more like a one time thingy that you need to fetch the current login status on app initialization, I don't think it needs any reactivity, you can go with AppInitializer and set the login status there, this way you won't need to show any loaders and there won't be any screen flickers on initialization due to state change.

Comment: You can mix it with what @DeborahK mentioned to make the login status reactive so you'll basically have a signal in your service whose initial state is set during app initialization phase using  [APP_INITIALIZER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER) and then after that you can use that signal wherever you want with the added bonus of better reactivity when updating that signal.

Comment: Alright, it is good to use a Service as a state management? I know I can use RxJS, but it seems service can be more easy to use and use also as a state management. @Yogi

Comment: Service vs RxJS doesn't seem like much logical to be honest, It's more of like RxJS vs Signal, you can do whatever you're doing using RxJs Subject wrapped in a service but this is where signals make it even easier, in your specific scenario, you're not gonna need to asynchronously update the state after it has been initially set, even for state like "isLoggedIn", you'll be updating it synchronously(when user clicks on log out button or something) so signals make more sense and it'll later on help you to get rid of zone.js completely.